# Value is not a String - StrongLoop

Tags: node.js, angular, strongloop

I am using strong loop for api creation. But it is giving me error. Properties of my json file are :

```
"properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "Number"
    },
    "name": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "language": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "timezone": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "labelId": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false,
      "default": 0
    },
    "street": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "contact": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false
    },
    "maincontact": {
      "type": "number",
      "required": false
    },
    "visitorTypes": {
      "type": "array",
      "required": false
    },
    "activeVisitorAvatar": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "activeLegalDocument": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "legalDocuments": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "logo": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "logoType": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "logoSmall": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "logoSmallType": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": false
    },
    "activeSignOut": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "activePrint": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "activeScanTemperature": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "printerIp": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "activeVoicePrompt": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "mandatoryCompanyName": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "mandatoryPhoneNumber": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "sliders": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "slidersCount": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "accountId": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "visitorsignouttime": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "signoutLink": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "signoutnotification": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "deviceofflinenotification": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "deviceonlinenotification": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "emergencyAlert": {
      "type": "object"
    },
    "autoSignOut": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "signOutTime": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "signOutPin": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "questionsEnabled": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "questions": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "logicalQuestionnaire": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "isEnableTemperatureCheck": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "disableTemperatureCheckScreen": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "isEnableQrCodeWithPinInside": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "isEnableComplianceAlerts": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "alertsWatchlistPriority": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "alertsCompliancePriority": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "eventNames": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "rooms": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "selfie": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "displayCompany": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "pagination": {
      "type": "boolean"
    }
  },
```

My body is as follows:

```
let body = JSON.stringify({
      id,
      name,
      street,
      timezone: this.timezone,
      activeVisitorAvatar,
      activeLegalDocument,
      legalDocuments,
      visitorTypes,
      activeSignOut,
      activeScanTemperature,
      activePrint,
      printerIp,
      labelId,
      activeVoicePrompt,
      mandatoryCompanyName,
      mandatoryPhoneNumber,
      mandatoryAnswersToQuestions,
      visitorsignouttime,
      signoutLink,
      signoutnotification,
      deviceofflinenotification,
      deviceonlinenotification,
      emergencyMessages: this.getEmergencyMessages(),
      address: this.address,
      autoSignOut,
      signOutTime,
      signOutPin,
      questionsEnabled,
      questions: this.getQuestions(),
      logicalQuestionnaire: this.getLogicalQuestionnaire(),
      accountId,
      isEnableRememberMeForFullUIFlow,
      isEnableTemperatureCheck,
      isEnableQrCodeWithPinInside,
      isEnableComplianceAlerts,
      alertsWatchlistPriority,
      alertsCompliancePriority,
      selfie,
      displayCompany,
      temperatureThreshold: {
        maximum: Number(temperatureMax),
        minimum: Number(temperatureMin),
        displayTextFormat: this.curr.temperatureThreshold.displayTextFormat,
      },
      pagination,
      gdpr: {
        isActive: this.curr.gdpr.isActive,
        days: gdprDays,
      },
      purposes /*filter(purposes, (item) => item.id)*/,
      isEnableIfThenQuestionnaire: isEnableIfThenQuestionnaire,
      visitorQueueDisplay,
      autoRefreshEntries: { enabled: autoRefreshEntries, interval: Number(autoRefreshEntriesInterval) },
      visitor_email,
    });
```

But i am receiving error `{"error":{"statusCode":400,"name":"Error","message":"Value is not a string.","stack":"Error: Value is not a string.\n    at Object.validate`

I am stuck here ! Have tried changing the data type in json file but didn't help also can't tell which parameter is causing the error. All the values are coming from front end html and angular. My dependencies are as follows :

```
"loopback": "^3.0.0",
"loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
"loopback-component-explorer": "^2.4.0",
"loopback-component-storage": "^3.0.0",
"loopback-connector-mongodb": "3.0.1",
```

the network request call i am making is :

```
try {
      this.http
        .post('/api/sites/edit?access_token=' + this.token, body, {
          headers: contentHeaders,
        })
        .subscribe(
          (response) => {
            this.hideFlag = true;
            this.toastr.success('Saved!');
            this.http
              .post(
                'api/users/setFeaturesByAccountId',
                {},
                {
                  params: {
                    access_token: this.token,
                    listFeatures: this.listFeature,
                    accountId: this.curr.accountId,
                  },
                },
              )
              .subscribe();
          },
          (error) => {
            this.hideFlag = true;
            this.toastr.error('Error');
            this.showError = error.json().error;
            console.log(error.text());
          },
        );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code that's responsible for making the network request itself

Comment: What is the value of `name`

Comment: @Ayzrian OG site is the passed value from front end

Comment: @AbirTaheer I have added the network call to the question.

Comment: You defined the `body` variable as a stringified json `let body = JSON.stringify({` but my suspicion is that the second parameter of the `http.post` method is expecting a javascript object and not a stringified json. Have you tried that already?

Comment: @AbirTaheer you are talking about name param ? it is string not tried to convert into object. i have tried removing json.stringfy() but that doesn't work either

Comment: Can you post the value of your `body` variable. Seems one of the properties has the wrong type.

Comment: Yeah,  but to see what types the properties have, we have to see its value. Because nobody knows what the various variables are, you put in that object

Comment: i am try to console.log the body, but it is not printing anything in chrome console. In fact, my whole project is not printing anything with console.log. what is the issue ?

Comment: @AbirTaheer I am facing issue ... when i transfer my app from loop back 2 to 3, some parameters start giving error that there data type is not string or number. They are not passed correctly according to the models. How to solve this ? the app is working fine on loop back 2 but when transfer to 3 it starts giving such errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the error was that loopback 3 doesn't type cast correctly. I have to check which variable was not casting correct and then in my middleware parse accordingly.

```
if(req.body.accountId){
    var numberId = parseInt(req.body.accountId);
    req.body.accountId = numberId;
}
```

Not a perfect solution but a work around!